# How do I load an rtf file to a WPF RichTextBox in Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, richtextbox

Anyone know hoe I can load an rtf file to a wpf RichTextBox?

In Windows.Forms I would do this

```
RichTextFile.Loadfile(c:\myfile.rtf)
```

but I don't know how to achieve the same in WPF!

Thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 6):

Not sure about PowerShell, but the RichTextBox has a Document property that you use can load a RTF file.
Here is sample, plus some good sites that helped me:

- [Some tricks for working with WPF’s RichTextBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2006/01/14/512825.aspx)
- [WPF RichTextBox](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WPFRichTextBox09072008194855PM/WPFRichTextBox.aspx)
- [WPF RichTextBox: How To Load, Edit and Save Rich Text Format](http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2010/03/01/wpf-richtextbox-how-to-load-edit-and-save-rich-text-format.aspx)

Here is the XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <RichTextBox Height="200" x:Name="rtb"/>
    <Button Content="Load" Click="Button_Click" Width="50" />
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the button click event to load the RTF:

```
public partial class MainView : Window
{
  public MainView()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
     TextRange textRange;
     System.IO.FileStream fileStream;

     if (System.IO.File.Exists("Document.rtf"))
     {
        textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
        using (fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream("Document.rtf", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
           textRange.Load(fileStream, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
        }
     }
  }
}
```