# Exception "bool? does not contain a definition for ok"

Tags: c#, xaml

I am design an application and I am trying to put the string from a file and try to put it into my richtextbox

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYIfy.png)

but their is a problem and that is

xaml file code

```
<Menu Header="File">
<MenuItem Header="_Open..." Name="open" InputGestureText="Ctrl+O" Click="open_click">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>


                        <Image Source="open-icon.png" Width="25" Height="25"></Image>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
</Menu>
<RichTextBox x:Name="richTextBox" Height="290" Width="508" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True">
        <FlowDocument>
            <Paragraph>
                <Run Name="test" Text=""/>
            </Paragraph>
        </FlowDocument>
    </RichTextBox>
```

cs file code

```
private void open_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog o = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        RichTextBox richtextbox = new RichTextBox();
        o.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        o.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";//working method//    Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        o.RestoreDirectory = true;
        if (o.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.ok)
            richtextbox1.LoadFile(o.FileName,FrameworkRichTextComposition.PlainText);
    }
```

the error comes on the line if statement and the underline object is "DialogResult.OK"
means that the "DialogResult.OK" is underline
and loadFile is also underline

I think that I am missing something in my xaml file or I am missing something else in my code

second error picture

here it is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqNIl.png)

Comment: If you hover the mouse over the underline, what is the error?  We cannot see your screen!  Remember that C# is case sensitive.  Are you sure it's `DialogResult.ok` (lowercase)?

Comment: Please write what the errors are saying !

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: ok I am sharing an image when I hover mouse on it

Comment: sir please click on "image description here" link to view the image

Comment: try DialogResult.OK instead DialogResult.ok

Comment: It's not a case problem, guys. `Window.DialogResult` is of type `bool?`, and `Window.ShowDialog()` returns `bool?`

Comment: same error on "DialogResult.OK"

Comment: I have fix the if error by using the below answer by @
 
Ed Plunkett

Comment: now the second error

Answer (score 1):

`Window.ShowDialog()` returns `bool?`. The `DialogResult` you're trying to compare it to is a property of the parent window, and you shouldn't be comparing anything to it. I think you might have it mixed up with `MessageBoxResult`, which is returned by `MessageBox.Show()`. `MessageBoxResult.OK` is a thing, but it's a different thing.

Here's what you want for `ShowDialog()`:

```
if (o.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault())
    richtextbox1.LoadFile(o.FileName,FrameworkRichTextComposition.PlainText);
```

Or this:

```
if ((bool)o.ShowDialog())
    richtextbox1.LoadFile(o.FileName,FrameworkRichTextComposition.PlainText);
```

## UPDATE

The second problem that you have is that the WPF RichTextBox control has no `LoadFile` method, unlike the winforms version. [This answer illustrates how to load a rich text file into a WPF RichTextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628657/424129).

Comment: sir loadFile is not working I have uploaded another image which is placed at the end of my question post please see that and inform me